# Box shadow gets inner padding added

Tags: css, class, wordpress-theming, padding, box-shadow

Padding appears when box-shadow is added to image div, in WordPress theme, and I have no idea why.

> style="box-shadow:0 10px 30px 0 rgba(49,52,57,.3),0 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.08)"

This exact shadow works fine for the themes' own pictures, but when i add it to mine 30 some px padding righ, left and 10xp bottom is added.

[padding inside box-shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1znX.png)

It shouldnt be affected by any CSS classes since the padding is not in the style attributes, and doesnt show when the the style is erased.

Any one have any idea whats going on?

[When the box-shadow style is erased the padding dissapears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmCZu.png)

Comment: Please add code snippet.

Comment: the box shadow is not adding ... but the box shadow is making the padding visible as without shadow you were not able to see it

Comment: No, thats not the case. Another image I added that has mostly white and was on a light-blue background shows clearly how the padding between the image and the box-shadow is the same hue light-blue, so its somehow the shadow that adds the padding.

Comment: The original code for the image is like this:
<div class="col-sm-5 bg-image shadow-large-black revert-classes-holder" data-bg="image"></div>
And shows no padding on the demo page. Then when I insert an image from my media library into the code the padding shows up, and can only be removed by removing the class "shadow-large-black" but then the shadow also is removed. So I copied the box-shadow style that is in the style sheet for the theme, and pasted it inline like I showed originally, but that still adds the padding.

Comment: I got the padding to go away by adding inline CSS like this:

`style="box-shadow:0 10px 30px 0 rgba(49,52,57,.3),0 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.08); padding: 0px;`

but it only took away the padding on the sides, for some reason the bottom padding stays. Have tried with padding-bottom: -8px; to get rid of it but that doesnt work. It looks better than before but its irritating not to be able to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: @M.Sill - did you ever find a way to get rid of the bottom padding?  I am having the same issue and it is quite irritating.  Nothing seems to get rid of it.